# It is possible to lock the screen orientation of the phone only when you want? (dynamically)

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation

I have an application that can be viewed with landscape and portrait mode. `I'm not using` `onConfigurationChanged()` and `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` and the screen orientation change is working perfectly.

But now, i have a small problem. I want to learn to lock the screen orientation change of the screen. I mean that for example, when the user press a "lock" button, the screen orientation must be locked and it must not change, and when the user press again that button, the screen orientation must get unlocked

¿how can i lock the screen orientation dinamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For locking,

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

For unlocking,

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

where "activity" is your current Activity, in which you want to lock.